# Replicating a VLOOKUP (with column insertion) in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to replicate a VLOOKUP I have done in Excel in SSMS. I have two tables - table 1 is an application master listing, table 2 is an application listing. I want to simply verify that every column in table 1 has an identical match in table two. I also want to have my results populate with an inserted column, column B with the results.

I have already done a very straight forward VLOOKUP in Excel with a 1:1 match. I now have Col A with the application master listing names, and then the new lookup column B with the 1:1 match.

Does anyone know how to go about this in SQL?

Comment: left join table2 to table1. If there are any nulls for the table2 primary key, then the table1 value doesn't have a match in table2.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to go about removing duplicates from tables before joining? Right now each table has about 1/2 duplicates. In Excel I was able to easily remove duplicates and then VLOOKUP, but I am unsure on how to do that in SQL without re-loading data. @DeanOC

Comment: Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: I'm with Jason. I'm not sure what you're really looking for either. However, try looking at documentation for SQL's `DISTINCT` keyword if you're wanting to deduplicate a select statement.